# Gurgling pipes after shower

Tags: plumbing

After taking a shower and then flushing the toilet, we get gurgling sound in the kitchen sink.

We have had the plumbing snaked which didn't help, kept happening. Then the plumber jetted the entire line and video scoped to make sure the lines were cleaned. The jetting got a lot slag out of the lines but it still gurgles occasionally. The plumber is saying it is because we installed the 1.3 gal flush toilets, although it gurgled before we installed the.

It doesn't make sense to me, I saw the video camera, the pipes are clean, what could cause this?

Help!

Comment: Venting problem?

Answer (score 2):

The kitchen sink is not vented well enough.

Does the sink have an air admittance valve? It could be clogged.

Otherwise it is just poor venting design. My bathroom sink does the same thing every time the dishwasher dumps.

It is not a major issue as long as you use the sink frequently it will refill the trap with water.

Good luck!